# Autofill webview form

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have a webview which opens [this website](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html). As we can see it has an input field. I want to autofill that input field with my data and auto click on submit button. Here is what I am trying for autofill but its not working.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    String url = "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html", pnrNumber = "";
    ProgressBar pb;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private Tracker mTracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_website);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {


        pnrNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("pnrNumber");

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.White), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl(url);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                pb.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    pb.setProgress(0);
                }
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
                v.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView v, String url) {
                v.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms[0].lccp_pnrno1.value = '"+pnrNumber+"';");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mTracker.setScreenName("WebView Fragment with " + url);
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        webView.stopLoading();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The rest of your onStop() code.
        webView.stopLoading();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something.?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to autofill and submit it straight away, why don't you just already send a POST request straight to that page to get the contents you desire?

All you gotta do, is do a POST request to this page:

http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnstat_cgi_8238.cgi

With POST data:
lccp_cap_value, 
lccp_capinp_value, 
lccp_pnrno1

The pnrno1 is the value you input there. The cap value and capinp values for me are 24357. Recheck that are they the same for you as well. Not sure that are they dynamic or static.

Other than that, I think that it's not possible to achieve this without hooking some kind of an external JavaScript file to it. But the POST solution should work (if the cap and capinp values are not dynamic).

Comment: How did you check the lccp_cap_value and lccp_capinp_value.? Also since I will be sending the request from an app with different PNRs will it work with same values.?

Comment: I checked it by checking the HTML source of your given webpage. On line 618 and 619 are the cap and capinp values. And yes, you can try leaving the cap and capinp values static (24357) and just change the pnrno1 value. That worked for me.

Comment: I am not able to get any result for the same. http://imgur.com/K4V5xdM I am checking PNR 4122187431

Comment: Sorry added wrong pic. http://imgur.com/a/h6mRm I am strll not able to get the result.

Comment: Just tested it myself with PHP cURL. You must set the referer to the request.
Referer:http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html
If that is set, it will allow you to make "remote" calls to it.

Here's a pastebin link to the PHP source: http://pastebin.com/LYv7fJF6

Comment: Okay. By the way is it possible to just auto fill the form with PNR number and let the user click submit button.?

Comment: Depends how you want to do it. You can ask the PNR number separately and then post it to that site or if you still want to load the page and let the end-user click the submit from there, then check that does your javascript code part get executed properly (i.e. does it pick the correct form etc).